# (android)Как внести изменения в библиотеку (ресурсы) которая подключена к проекту?

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос,в сети нашел библиотеку,но данная библиотека не поддерживает руск.язык (нет перевода файла string для ру региона) я залез в корень библиотеки и сделал изменения. Студия сразу дает мне понять,что после ребилда изменения не сохраняться.
На скриншоте все указал,возможно ли как-то изменить ситуацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вас там в дереве проекта какой вид выбран? Не Packages  случайно? Смените на Project, если так.

Comment: @ Suvitruf 
т.е проблема в том,что я выбрал в ветке тип project?))))

Comment: Не-не, такая проблема возникает, если файлы не там лежат, где надо. А такое бывает, если тип выбран Packages. Надо сменить на project и убедиться, что файлы где надо лежат.

Comment: @ Suvitruf
обновил шапку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь ясно. Вы пытаетесь править ресурсы в автогенерируемых директориях.

Я не вижу всей структуры вашего проекта, но ресурсы ваши должны быть не в папке build, а в **src/main/res/values**.